# How to convert (or transform) from one range to another?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have score ranges `min score = 40` and `max score = 60`. I have same gpa ranges too `1.00 - 1.99`.

Which formula I can use to calculate the gpa.  Like If I entered `45` then it should print `1.25`.

Range of score and grade can be different.

P.S. I am a web developer, and I am a little poor in Math. I need to apply this formula in my coding.

Comment: I would change the title to something like `How to convert (or transform) from one range to another`.

Comment: Changed.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shift numbers into a different range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914823/shift-numbers-into-a-different-range)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let the following denote:

- $S$: input score
- $S_{min}$: min score
- $S_{max}$: max score
- $G_{min}$: min gpa
- $G_{max}$: max gpa
- $G$: output gpa

Then your formula is:

$$G=\frac{(S-S_{min})\cdot(G_{max}-G_{min})}{S_{max}-S_{min}}+G_{min}$$

Comment: @SumitMadan: You're welcome :)

Comment: Does this method allow range like this [-100, 100]?

Comment: @VansFannel: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The general form of this question on how to map the interval $[a,b]$ onto the interval $[c,d]$ was answered in  [Shift numbers into a different range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914823/shift-numbers-into-a-different-range) (including a derivation) using the following expression
$$f(t) = c + \left(\frac{d-c}{b-a}\right)(t-a)$$
So to map the interval $[40,60]$ onto the interval $[1.0,2.0]$ use
\begin{align}
f(t) &= 1.0 + \left(\frac{2.0-1.0}{60-40}\right)(t-40) \\
     &= 1.0 + \left(\frac{t-40}{20}\right)
\end{align}
Using your example score of $45$
\begin{align}
f(45) &= 1.0 + \left(\frac{45-40}{20}\right) \\
      &= 1.25
\end{align}