# How to convert an interval to different one

Tags: arithmetic

I have a variable x in the interval [-30; 30]. I need to convert this interval so x would be in the interval [0; 1]. What I mean is like this:

```
original x:     -30 .. -20 ... -10 .... 0 .... 10 .... 20 ... 30

new x:           0  .. 0.16 .. 0.32 .. 0.5 .. 0.66 .. 0.83 ..  1
```

New x values correspond to the original x values. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Just to illustrate what Travis answered, report on a plot the new $x$ as a function of the original value. Do you see what you have ? So, guess (find) the equation. Good problem !

Comment: Duplicate and more generic solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914823/shift-numbers-into-a-different-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is shift and then scale... take a value $x\in [-30, 30]$ and add 30 to it.  Then $x+30\in [0, 60]$.  Finally, divide by 60, $(x+30)/60\in [0, 1]$.