# Need help converting log to linear

Tags: logarithms

This is my first post to stackexchange.  I have a set of base-ten log values in the range 0 to 1. I want to linearize these into values which are also in the range 0 to 1.  Is it possible?  If so, how?  If not, am I thinking about the problem the wrong way, and can you steer me in the right direction?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914823/shift-numbers-into-a-different-range/914843) on mathstackexchange.

Let k equal one of the long base ten values

Raise 10 to the kth power to linearize it.  This gives a value in the range 1 to 10.

Now use the "Shift numbers into a different range" formula to transform the value back into the range 0 to 1.  The transformation is simple: (10^k-1)/9.

I welcome comments on this solution.  Is it correct?

Comment: In effect your function is $\frac19(10^k-1)$. If that works for you then it works for you. But you have lost some of the properties of anti-logarithms in the process.

Comment: Thank you!  I realized that was the solution almost as soon as I had posted the question.  Thanks for confirming!